# Import csv file in sqlite3 table using query

Tags: visual-c++, sqlite, mfc

I need to import csv file in sqlite3 table. I am using Visual studio (MFC applciation).
I know how to import csv using command prompt.

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import your.csv Table_Name
```

This is working fine. But I need to perform similar operation using some query in program.
How can I do this using query in my program?

Answer (score 0):

The `.import` command is implemented by the `sqlite3` command-line shell.

If you want to do the same in your program, you have to copy that code from the shell's source code ([shell.c](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/artifact/b80396d2fadce468)).